# Format Time in GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, gridview, telerik

I have a field in my sql table that has a data type of Time(0). If I bind my gridviewcolumn to it without formatting it populates fine, just doesnt look nice and is in 24 hour format.

I need to show just a "2:00 PM" format for ex. but nothing has worked to format this data.

```
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Hours Start" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursStart}" DataFormatString="{}{0:hh:mm tt}" />
```

Also tried...

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Hours End" Width="75" IsFilterable="True" IsSortable="True">
  <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HoursEnd, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm tt}}" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this : `DataFormatString = "{0:t}"`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format the column and have a cell template defined at the same time. If you have a cell template defined then you need to format your data in there.

Comment: It sounds to me like the format and the template were 2 different methods that were attempted unsuccessfully. Not necessarily that they tried both at the same time. Can you edit your answer to show the correct way to get the format if you know it?